# wrap_socket() got an unexpected keyword argument '_context'

Tags: python, django, python-requests, gunicorn, eventlet

I'm currently trying to put in production a django project using nginx and gunicorn for the first time.
The project consist on a register page in which the user access, fills a form and the data is used to make a request to another server to create a profile using the data taken from the form of my app.

To do such task I have the following libraries:

- requests 2.22.0
- gunicorn 20.0.4
- eventlet 0.25.1 (with greenlet 0.4.15)

The project was entirely tested and functional in a testing environment inside an ubuntu 18.04 virtual machine.

Now the server in production is a Debian 10. Every web page of the project works correctly and so does the Django admin page. The thing is that when I try to fill the form to actually register on the database of the second server it returns the following error:

```
    Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://reg.rocstar.tv/register/customer/

Django Version: 2.2.7
Python Version: 3.7.5
Installed Applications:
['reg.apps.RegConfig',
 'import_export',
 'crispy_forms',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/home/rocstar/.local/share/virtualenvs/register-page-Z_TgQ-vY/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/rocstar/.local/share/virtualenvs/register-page-Z_TgQ-vY/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/rocstar/.local/share/virtualenvs/register-page-Z_TgQ-vY/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/rocstar/register-page/register_page/reg/views.py" in CustomerRegister
  63.                 r_login = requests.post("https://nb.mc.rocstar.tv/int/login", data = {"username" : CMS_user, "password" : CMS_pass}, allow_redirects = False)

File "/home/rocstar/.local/share/virtualenvs/register-page-Z_TgQ-vY/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py" in post
  116.     return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)

File "/home/rocstar/.local/share/virtualenvs/register-page-Z_TgQ-vY/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py" in request
  60.         return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)

File "/home/rocstar/.local/share/virtualenvs/register-page-Z_TgQ-vY/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py" in request
  533.         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)

File "/home/rocstar/.local/share/virtualenvs/register-page-Z_TgQ-vY/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py" in send
  646.         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)

File "/home/rocstar/.local/share/virtualenvs/register-page-Z_TgQ-vY/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py" in send
  449.                     timeout=timeout

File "/home/rocstar/.local/share/virtualenvs/register-page-Z_TgQ-vY/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py" in urlopen
  672.                 chunked=chunked,

File "/home/rocstar/.local/share/virtualenvs/register-page-Z_TgQ-vY/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py" in _make_request
  376.             self._validate_conn(conn)

File "/home/rocstar/.local/share/virtualenvs/register-page-Z_TgQ-vY/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py" in _validate_conn
  994.             conn.connect()

File "/home/rocstar/.local/share/virtualenvs/register-page-Z_TgQ-vY/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py" in connect
  394.             ssl_context=context,

File "/home/rocstar/.local/share/virtualenvs/register-page-Z_TgQ-vY/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py" in ssl_wrap_socket
  370.             return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)

File "/home/rocstar/.local/share/virtualenvs/register-page-Z_TgQ-vY/lib/python3.7/site-packages/eventlet/green/ssl.py" in wrap_socket
  438.             return GreenSSLSocket(sock, *a, _context=self, **kw)

File "/home/rocstar/.local/share/virtualenvs/register-page-Z_TgQ-vY/lib/python3.7/site-packages/eventlet/green/ssl.py" in __new__
  76.                     *args, **kw

Exception Type: TypeError at /register/customer/
Exception Value: wrap_socket() got an unexpected keyword argument '_context'
```

The traceback shows an error when using requests command to access the login API of the second server which is needed to then use the profile creation API.

I really don't understand which is the problem because as I said is the first time I work with these tools. So any help is more than welcomed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [wrap\_socket() got an unexpected keyword argument '\_context' and deserialize(error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57712218/wrap-socket-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-context-and-deserializeerro)

Comment: Thanks for the response, this was fixed months ago, honestly i don't remember what was the issue if i can figure it out i will update the post